# Sort post by custom field numeric value

Tags: query-posts

I am trying the way to sort post from custom field numeric value.

Here is my query:

```
query_posts( 'cat=2684' );
```

how to tell to use the custom field "sort_number" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort your posts by a numeric value in a custom field your query would look like this:

```
query_posts('cat=2684&meta_key=yourCFkey&orderby=meta_value_num');
```